# gettext not translating

Tags: php, gettext

I installed the php-gettext package, and `phpinfo()` shows that gettext is enabled.

My app.po looks like:

```
msgid "Welcome" 
msgstr "Willkommen auf meiner Homepage!"

msgid "Hier you can find stuff about me."
msgstr "Hier finden Sie Informationen uber mich."`
```

My php file looks like:

```
putenv('LC_ALL=de_DE');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');
bindtextdomain("app", "./lang");
textdomain("app");

echo gettext("Welcome");
echo _('Hier you can find stuff about me.');
```

The app.mo is in `./lang/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/`

The text isn't getting translated and I'm not getting any error messages.

Comment: An interesting alternative to gettext is [`Zend_Translate`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html).

Comment: "Hier you can find stuff about me" is an interesting translation...

Comment: @Tokk: That's true denglisch ;-)

Comment: @couchpot: The php-gettext package is PHP's gettext library, isn't it? Or do you refer to this: http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/php-gettext/

Comment: I installed the ubuntu package

Comment: have you tried to use a absolute path not a relative one? maybe try `dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang'`

Comment: have you tried to compile the po file to a mo file?

Comment: Yeah. Try it in console first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you checked if de_DE is installed as a locale?

Check it with `locale -a`.

If not, generate it with `locale-gen de_DE`.

Comment: Where do you do this? Do I need to type this in command prompt?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the question. Where do I put `locale -a`?

Comment: `locale -a` and `locale-gen` are commands, the author meant exectuting them in the shell prompt. I have no idea if they exist on Windows builds.