# Making a website support multiple languages in PHP

Tags: php, multilingual

I searched and searched google and various forums for the problem and have seen various methods e.g. using databases, arrays, constants, files etc..

and also internationalization and localization..

This much diversity has confused me enough..

Can someone please help me to guide the best possible approach towards making a multilingual website in PHP?

or how can i get started with localization concept in case its the best (which seems to be).
does l10n or i18n requires any special configuarations on the webserver part? or it can be implemented on any of the apache webserver out there which modifying any of the conf files as the hosting providers does not allows to change these settings.

is there any good class which i can use?

thanks!

Comment: Since you say you have already googled, I assume you also have searched StackOverflow. Please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4197012/edit) and point out why [none of these help solving your question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=multilanguage+php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at: [Internationalization of Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.i18n.html) which is pretty easy to use.

Comment: how can i use zend form or zend translate classes independently? without using the whole zend framework?? as i am more into procedural language.

Comment: You can use Zend packages without the whole Framework. It works pretty simple.. It's just a switch between `array with language A` and `array with language B`, `array with language C`, and so on..

Comment: I just wrote a how-to-use-Zend-Form in non-ZF applications, you might wanna read it if you still have trouble with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132036/gettext-php5-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this feature:

1. You can use GNU's GetText: Needs to have the PHP extension installed, but there's an available workaround in Wordpress's code
2. You can use INI files and parse them as constants
3. You can use the ZEND framework as the translation API

Answers are not good without taking part of something, so my propossition is to use the GetText API, which is outstading!

Best regards,
David

Comment: where can i get the dive into gettext api code? and see for some examples? would this also require the gettext php extension to be installed? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the Zend Framework which offers also classes for translation.

Comment: I like the idea; as i mentioned earlier the only problem is that i dont fully want to use the zend framework? and as "Enrico Pallazzo" mentioned using packages.. can you please provide me with a quick start on how to use these packages? thanks